# How can I separate a full path into directory and filename?

Tags: perl

```
$a = '/etc/init/tree/errrocodr/a.txt'
```

I want to extract  `/etc/init/tree/errrocodr/`  to `$dir` and `a.txt` to `$file`.  How can I do that?

*(Editor's note: the original question presumed that you needed a regular expression for that.)*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use [Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html):

```
use File::Basename;
$fullspec = "/etc/init/tree/errrocodr/a.txt";

my($file, $dir, $ext) = fileparse($fullspec);
print "Directory: " . $dir . "\n";
print "File:      " . $file . "\n";
print "Suffix:    " . $ext . "\n\n";

my($file, $dir, $ext) = fileparse($fullspec, qr/\.[^.]*/);
print "Directory: " . $dir . "\n";
print "File:      " . $file . "\n";
print "Suffix:    " . $ext . "\n";
```

You can see this returning the results you requested but it's also capable of capturing the extensions as well (in the latter section above):

```
Directory: /etc/init/tree/errrocodr/
File:      a.txt
Suffix:

Directory: /etc/init/tree/errrocodr/
File:      a
Suffix:    .txt
```

Comment: Or alternatively, have a look at File::Spec->splitpath(), which separates out the volume as well (if you happen to be on a platform that has such a thing). The advantage of either package is that they are standard and portable.

Answer (score 16):

you don't need a regex for this, you can use dirname():

```
use File::Basename;
my $dir = dirname($a)
```

however this regex will work:

```
my $dir = $a
$dir =~ s/(.*)\/.*$/$1/
```

Comment: +1, but IMHO should not use the variable `$a` in your example even if the OP mistakenly did. It is used for `sort`

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex solution is a perfectly legitimate need - since my googling for exactly that brought me here. I want to pull out a filename in a group that's part of a larger match expression - here's my attempt:

```
~> echo "/a/b/c/d" | perl -ne '/(?<dir>\/(\w+\/)*)(?<file>\w+)/ && print "dir $+{dir}  file $+{file}\n";'
dir /a/b/c/  file d
```

Answer (score 1):

try this; it works at least for the filename, but when you modify it, it also gives you the direction:
You can also modify it on UNIX-systems for the \ instead if / or to use them both with |

```
$filename =~ s/(^.*\/)//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@array = split("/", $a);`
and then `$array[-1]` is your file name.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
    $a =~ m#^(.*?)([^/]*)$#;
   ($dir,$file)  = ($1,$2);
```

But, as other said, it's better to just use `Basename` for this.

And, BTW, better avoid `$a` and `$b` as variable names, as they have a special meaning, for `sort` function.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will work:

```
@^(.+/)/([^/]+)$@
```