# Perl: divide the path into directory and file name

Tags: regex, perl, path

In my Perl script, I want divide the path string into two strings: the directory and file name. 
For example, for example ./output/try.txt split into ./output and try.txt
Now I use 
`$path =~ s/(\/?)[^\/]*$/${1}/`

can get the directory part.
A little confused about the second part.
I am new for regular expression, need some help.

Based on my own test I find a good way: 
`$path = "./output/try.txt"`
`$dir = $path`
`$dir =~ s/([^\/]*$)//;` 
`$file = $1`

use s to match the file name with [^/]*$, and replace it with empty, then can get $dir. and the mateched part $1 will be $file.
Hope it is helpful

Comment: I think you already have an answer for this in stackoverflow. Try to check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512526/how-can-i-separate-a-full-path-into-directory-and-filename

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [m](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html)atch operator :

```
$ perl -e '
    my $fp = "/path/to/file.pl";
    my ($path, $file) = $fp =~ m!(.*)/(.*)!;
    print "path=$path\nfile=$file\n"
'
```

or :

```
$ perl -e '
    $fp = "/path/to/file.pl";
    $fp =~ m!(.*)/(.*)! and print "path=$1\nfile=$2\n"
'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
path=/path/to
file=file.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use the core module [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use File::Basename;

my $fullname = './output/try.txt';
my $basename = basename($fullname);
my $dirname  = dirname($fullname);
say $fullname;
say $basename;
say $dirname;
```

**Output:**

```
./output/try.txt
try.txt
./output
```